# Using rmvString to delete some text and a number in Outlook script

Tags: vba, email, replace, outlook

I'm using a VBA script to abstract and format data from incoming emails.

I'm currently trying to devise a way to remove some text and a 1 to 5 digit number after the text.

The text is always the word "default" and the number can be from 1 to 99999 (such as "default 23453" or "default 9"). The number could also not exist (just the word "default").

I'm currently use the string:

**`rmvString = Replace(rmvString, "default ", "")`**

and that removes the word default. But now I want to remove the number that usually follows the word default. Examples.

---

Input email:
Default 2332 additional text comes here.

Output:
additional text comes here.

---

Another possible input (no number):
Default additional text comes here.

Output:
additional text comes here.

---

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click *Tools*, *References* and add "*Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5*" then you can use a RegExp search & replace:

```
rmvString = "Hello default A" & vbCrLf & _
            "Hello DEFAULT 12 B" & vbCrLf & _
            "Hello default 123456 C" & vbCrLf

MsgBox rmvString

With New RegExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(default\s\d*\s*)" 'finds the string, a space, any digits, any space

    rmvString = .Replace(rmvString, "")
End With

MsgBox rmvString
```